# Source code not properly beautified

Tags: wordpress, bbcode

Being a new year and all, I thought that I'd start using nicer formatting for my blog on WordPress. I used the following syntax.

```
[sourcecode language="csharp"]
  String controlledData = originalData.Substring(0, 200);
[/sourcecode]
```

However, the text is all in black. So, I'm hitting the right bb-code but still do something wrong. What?

I tried to follow the advice of [this dude](http://en.blog.wordpress.com/2009/12/02/better-source-code-posting/).

Answer (score 0):

Try Syntax Highlighter plugin, I use "SyntaxHighlighter Evolved" and it's great and easy.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/

Comment: I'm not sure if that's going to help. According to the information on the page, it's extending the plugin I'm already using (and not getting the beautification). I'm afraid that whatever problem there is hindering me from getting classes colored, it will remain even if I change to another plugin. Could you check if the exact syntax I used shows colored *String* class? Thanks.

Comment: are you using any minify plugins? can you provide your website URL?

Comment: I haven't activated any plugins as far as I'm aware. Here's [the URL](http://konradviltersten.wordpress.com) to my blog (see the latest post, first this year). I didn't want to post it before because I don't want to be accused for self-promotion. There are two issues really. Most important is that the **second** code sample isn't colorified. The other is that the xml piece is put on the same line. It's supposed to be on three lines. Any suggestions are appreciated.